# How should I handle having a entities property be non-nullable while the column is nullable? - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

The database has nullabble columns, which I was told it was safe to assume would never have null data in them. The entity framework code was modeled under this assumpion. Some customer databases, however, I have found do in fact have the occasional null value in these columns. Entity Framework proceeds to blow up internally on using SqlReader to read these column by, for example, calling getDateTime on a null value.

The database schema was designed a long time ago, and cannot at this time be updated. In short, columns that should not be null, are sometimes null. The software enforces these columns to have appropriate values stored, not the database.

Our Entity Framework code was modeled assuming that the software has correctly done it's job, and that these columns that were not supposed to ever be null were simply not null.

In testing, I have found two customer's databases that somehow have null values in columns that should not, and entity framework is blowing up internally on trying to parse the errors. These are historic databases that still get loaded, but were probably caused by the software being more buggy 10+ years ago. These parsing errors are all SqlReader erroring on failing to call getDateTime on a null value for a non-nullable DateTime object, for example.

I can trial and error where it blows up, and manually change each property to be nullable (and then change the code to now handle the chance of it being nullable), however I do not want to make every single property nullable. Every null value I've seen so far could have been defaulted to an appropriate value.

I tried refactoring a property to be "PropertySafe" (to not break existing code), then made a new "Property" that was wired up, and let "PropertySafe"'s getter call Property and return an appropriate default on null. This is better, as the rest of the code does not have to be aware of this database schema flaw, however it is cumbersome to do over and over again, and I find it a little ugly. I also fear that some EFContext queries that grab one of these "Safe" properties would confused EF and force it to run them client side, which would be much less performant.

I took a dive at RelationalTypeMapping and ValueConverter's, thinking maybe there I could handle going from sql's "datetime not null" columns to a CLR DateTime property, defaulting when I need, however that does not work because the database has already been parsed at that point. I would need to override whereever it specifically is calling getDateTime on the SqlReader and intercept it there.

An example Entity/Property to Table/Column that fails is virtually the same as the following sample.

```
public class Entity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public class Configuration : BaseConfiguation<Entity> {
      protected override string TableName => "ENTITY_DUE_DATE";
      protected override void DoConfigure( EntityTypeBuilder<Entity> builder ) {
        builder.HasKey( x => new { x.Id } );
        builder.Property( x => x.Id ).HasColumnName( "ID" );
        builder.Property( x => x.DueDate ).HasColumnName( "DUEDATE" );
      }
    }
  }
```

with the SQL Schema

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITY_DUE_DATE  (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    DUEDATE DATETIME NULL
);
```

Where our DateTime mapping looks like

```
public class SqlServerDateTimeMapping : DateTimeTypeMapping {

    public SqlServerDateTimeMapping() : base( "DateTime", System.Data.DbType.DateTime ) { }

    protected SqlServerDateTimeMapping( RelationalTypeMappingParameters parameters ) : base( parameters ) { }

    public override string GenerateSqlLiteral( object value ) {
      if ( value is DateTime date ) {
        if ( date.Date != date ) {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail( "Time portions are not supported" );
        }
        return date.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
      }
      return base.GenerateSqlLiteral( value );
    }

    public override RelationalTypeMapping Clone( in RelationalTypeMappingInfo mappingInfo ) => new SqlServerDateTimeMapping();

    public override RelationalTypeMapping Clone( string storeType, int? size ) => new SqlServerDateTimeMapping();

    public override CoreTypeMapping Clone( ValueConverter converter ) => new SqlServerDateTimeMapping();
  }
```

As I said, I tried making a converter to plug into the SqlServerDateTimeMapping's Converter override, but I could not figure out how to handle it BEFORE/DURING the parsing of Sql. It seems the converter lets you convert between two CLR types, so post-parsing.

For the sake of completeness, this is my converter currently. It's outright wrong though.

```
public class NullableDateTimeToDateTimeConverter : ValueConverter<DateTime?, DateTime> {
    public NullableDateTimeToDateTimeConverter() : base(s => s ?? DateTime.MaxValue, x => x ) { }
  }
```

I expect to be able to have my Entity class's Property be non-nullable, keep the database column nullable, and have the entity framework engine handle returning a default value when it finds a null, whereas it currently blows up on parsing the null (specifically in SqlBuffer.GetDateTime() called by SqlReader.GetDateTime() inside any Context query, whether its context.EntityDueDate.ToList() or context.Set()).

Whatever the solution is, it would be ideal if my queries can still handled database-side rather than client side. So if I did

```
context.EntityDueDates.Where(x => x.DueDate > DateTime.UtcNow).ToList()
```

It would be best to be able to run that query on the database and not have to be returned client-side to do the

`DueDate ?? DEFAULT_VALUE`

logic, however it fits in there.

I should clarify, the solution should work for more than just DateTime. I'm just picking on DateTime because the one I manually fixed was DateTime, but examining the databases shows me that this same scenario will likely occur for a few int/int? differences as well. I would hope the solution given though can be applied between any nullable/non-nullable data types.

UPDATE:

I have a new lead. In the SqlServerDateTimeMapping class, I can override the method:

```
public override MethodInfo GetDataReaderMethod() {
      var methodInfo = base.GetDataReaderMethod();
      return methodInfo;
}
```

and inspect methodInfo. Sure enough, this is the method "GetDateTime", the very same that is crashing on parsing. My thought process is maybe I can somehow return my own method that can be invoked on SqlDataReader that handles null checking, or subclass SqlDataReader to override this method. I notice now though that GetDateTime takes a int as the parameter, refering to which column. Internally it calls IsDBNull before invoking to make sure it is not null. I was hoping a string was being passed I could override the parsing of, however it looks like this simply takes a column and uses SqlBuffer to get_dateTime on, which is who does the parsing

Comment: Probably stating the obvious, but I assume you can't just run a script that fills in the null values in the database?

Comment: I wish. If I fail to accomplish this, I can probably ask again with a stronger case, but our customers hate when we tamper with their data, so I was told to do what I can to just make this work. For the time being, that is off the table, but yes, that would be the simplest way to fix this haha

Comment: Sooner or later someone has to fix it. If you can get it work with custom converters, then you will be the only dev in the future who understands what is going on :) I think this will make the mess even bigger, and nobody will ever be able or willing to make any changes.

Comment: Totally hear you Marc. We are talking about building a new version of the software from scratch in the coming years, at which point this will be updated. It's been unanimously decided here that restarting from scratch is the best way to do a clean start. 19 year old legacy software doesn't update quickly. I'm picking and choosing my battles, with migrating over to a ORM that can be reused on a future C# server being my current goal. Hopefully one day we can enforce a new database schema and migrate over old data to it, but for now this is the most progressive direction I can bring it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the answer, however I am open to other solutions. This "solves" my answer, however it limits me to having one generic "Default" per type. Sometimes the "best" default might be DateTime.MinValue, sometimes DateTime.MaxValue, sometimes DateTime.UtcNow. Having one default has its flaws. I do think this answer does not create a performance hit, and I'm sure does not mess with the mappings in any way that might make work be done client side in a query.

My solution was to make a class, "ContextDbDataReaderDecorator", which can be implicitly converted back and forth between a DbDataReader. It stores the DbDataReader upon creation, and uses it for its own GetDataTimeSafe alternative method. The implicit conversion allows us to return it from the SqlServerDateTimeMapping's "GetDataReaderMethod" overload, as it can then be invoked on a DbDataReader despite not actually belonging to a DbDataReader.

My relational type mapping object looks like the following:

```
public class SqlServerDateTimeMapping : DateTimeTypeMapping {
    static MethodInfo s_getDateTimeSafeMethod = typeof( ContextDbDataReaderDecorator ).GetMethod( nameof( ContextDbDataReaderDecorator.GetDateTimeSafe ) );

    public SqlServerDateTimeMapping() : base( "DateTime", System.Data.DbType.DateTime ) {}

    protected SqlServerDateTimeMapping( RelationalTypeMappingParameters parameters ) : base( parameters ) {}

    public override string GenerateSqlLiteral( object value ) {
      if ( value is DateTime date ) {
        if ( date.Date != date ) {
          System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail( "Time portions are not supported" );
        }
        return date.ToString( "yyyy-MM-dd" );
      }
      return base.GenerateSqlLiteral( value );
    }


    public override MethodInfo GetDataReaderMethod() {
      return s_getDateTimeSafeMethod;
    }

    public override RelationalTypeMapping Clone( in RelationalTypeMappingInfo mappingInfo ) => new SqlServerDateTimeMapping();
    public override RelationalTypeMapping Clone( string storeType, int? size ) => new SqlServerDateTimeMapping();
    public override CoreTypeMapping Clone( ValueConverter converter ) => new SqlServerDateTimeMapping();
  }
```

and the ContextDbDataReaderDecorator class I created looks like the following:

```
public class ContextDbDataReaderDecorator {
    public DbDataReader DbDataReader { get; }

    public ContextDbDataReaderDecorator( DbDataReader inner ) {
      DbDataReader = inner;
    }

    public static implicit operator DbDataReader( ContextDbDataReaderDecorator self )  => self.DbDataReader;
    public static implicit operator ContextDbDataReaderDecorator( DbDataReader other ) => new ContextDbDataReaderDecorator( other );
    public DateTime GetDateTimeSafe( int ordinal ) => (DbDataReader.GetValue( ordinal ) as DateTime?) ?? new DateTime( 3000, 1, 1 );
    public int GetIntSafe(int ordinal) => (DbDataReader.GetValue( ordinal ) as int?) ?? 0;
    public long GetLongSafe( int ordinal ) => (DbDataReader.GetValue( ordinal ) as long?) ?? 0;
    public float GetFloatSafe(int ordinal) => (DbDataReader.GetValue( ordinal ) as float?) ?? 0.0f;
  }
```

Comment: I have accepted my answer as the correct answer due to no alternatives being posted after a week. Future readers, I would advise not going this path unless you absolutely must. I think its really cool Entity Framework had allowed this to be wired up so smoothly, however Gert Arnold and Marc are both absolutely correct in advising against this. It is a bandaid fix that masks the problem, hiding it from future coders. The better solution is to write a SQL script that copies the data (filling in nulls with defaults) into a temp table, clear the old table, alter its schema, then re-insert the data